# Opportunity object access when a record triggered flow is triggered by action of a platform licensed user

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a salesforce flow created on a custom object P, P is managed package custom object and child object of Opportunity.

There is another managed custom object B, B is child of P and also of Opportunity.

Now there is a record triggered flow which gets triggered on record creation of B, it reads parent of B -> P and from P it goes (B -> P -> Opportunity -> Custom field). I was expecting this flow to fail as it tries to read Opportunity custom field and record triggered flow was triggered by platform user which doesn't have access to Opportunity object

but this flow works fine. It is confusing. I understand that record triggered flow runs as system user and don't respect FLS but i was expecting it to be not able to read opportunity object field due to license limitations.

Answer (score 0):

System context means that the running user's permissions and FLS are ignored

"User permissions" in this case includes Object Permissions (i.e. CRUD)

> Flows run in user context or system context. For a flow running in user context, the running user’s profile and permission sets determine the object permissions and field-level access of the flow. For a flow that runs in system context, the flow access is determined by whether the flow runs in system context with sharing or without sharing.

While not the most artfully worded, the above says that in System context, the only variable is sharing/not sharing enforced which is all about record access, not permissions to CRUD. Everything else is accessible (exceptions when user is Guest User).

The [documentation for Apex User Mode versus System Mode](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_perms_enforcing.htm) is a bit clearer

> Apex generally runs in system context; that is, the current user's permissions and field-level security aren’t taken into account during code execution. Sharing rules, however, aren’t always bypassed: the class must be declared with the without sharing keyword in order to ensure that sharing rules aren’t enforced. Apex code that is executed with the executeAnonymous call and Connect in Apex always execute using the sharing rules of the current user. For more information on executeAnonymous, see Anonymous Blocks.
>
> To enforce field-level security (FLS) and **object permissions** of the running user, you can specify user-mode access for database operations. See Enforce User Mode for Database Operations. You can also enforce these permissions in your SOQL queries by using WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED. For more information, see Filter SOQL Queries Using WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED.